# In Entity Framework how do I wrap a database call with a call to another service and ensure they're always called together?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity framework model called Employee. Whenever I request a list of all Employee rows I first want to make a soap request to get any new employees from another system and update the sql database with them.

Is there some sort of binding that I could apply to the model or would I just have to add another model that calls both and call it instead.

I'm wanting to make it so that I can't call the employee list from the database directly without refreshing it at each place in the razor pages where I call it.

Comment: hmm i don't think its possible

Comment: Congrats, you've stumbled across one of the many reasons why EF (and ORMs in general) are not ideal in every situation. ORMs are great if your requirement is "take some DB rows, put them on a screen and maybe edit them:". Well, you've now got a scenario where you need more than that, but there's not a great way to accomplish it without just adding a new helper class with one method that does the service call, waits for it to finish the inserts, then does the EF call. And someone else would have to know that method exists outside of the normal EF flow, so it'll be easy to forget about.

Comment: @Graham: This is not a flaw of ORMs in any way. The same issue would apply when OP was using any other logic for data storage. Many solutions exist. When the DAL is abstract into a separate layer, it's perfectly possible to only expose methods which inherently include the additional logic, and prevent any consumer of the DAL assembly to access the database any other way.

Comment: @Flater, true, but if you've put EF behind a DAL, you have already sacrificed what is, imho, the main benefit of something like EF, which is the ability to modify and optimize queries right up to the View. If you have a DAL method that loads all Car Objects, but your view just wants to show their names, there's no query benefit to using EF behind the DAL layer. If your page model itself is EF-aware, then the "GetAllCars()" query is translated into just selecting the car names only, at runtime.

Comment: @Graham: It seems you misunderstand the purpose of ORMs. Passing the context down to the view is bad practice for many reasons (SRP being the main violation here), and not at all the main benefit of EF. EF's benefit comes from providing a high (but admittedly not complete) conversion from code to SQL. Effectively, a developer using EF (Code First) doesn't need to know one letter of SQL in order to work with their datastore. _["This creates, in effect, a "virtual object database" that can be used from within the programming language."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)_

Comment: @Graham: Secondly, it is contradictory to expect to force custom business logic (as per OP's question) yet not actually creating a layer for that custom business logic to reside or be enforced from. If you give your view unfettered access to EF, then you're also giving it the option to avoid your custom business logic. Your comment is effectively arguing that an approach which does not achieve the intended effect (leaking the DB to the view), does in fact not achieve the intended effect (creating an intermediary layer that separates the db and the view). That's a logical inevitability.

Comment: @Graham: `If you have a DAL method that loads all Car Objects, but your view just wants to show their names, there's no query benefit to using EF behind the DAL layer.` Nothing is preventing you from passing a `Func<Car,object>` parameter to your DAL, which it then uses to perform a `Select()` before instantiating its query. You seem to be arguing that something is impossible while in fact having skipped rudimentary problem solving steps such as method parametrization.

Comment: Whoah, you expose the EF-type Car PAST your DAL instead of handing them to the client as a different model? That would strike me as incorrect. Where are you disposing of your EF Context? If you return some Cars through the DAL, but their originating EF Context is already disposed, what happens when the client starts trying to walk the navigation properties of the Car? Would that not trigger an exception?

Comment: @Graham: Every issue you bring to the table is one that can be solved. We're in a circular argument here. You claim something is impossible, and when it is explained to you why it is actually possible, you move to the next topic and claim it is impossible again. I suggest you reevaluate claiming things are impossible until you've actually confirmed that they indeed are.

Comment: @Flater, I never said anything was impossible, I said ORMs "are not ideal in every situation". And what I'm suggesting now is that the drawbacks of an ORM might outweigh the benefits, if you put the ORM behind a DAL. Yes, every issue I've mentioned can be solved, but at what cost? Also, I was asking about the exception, not stating it, I am genuinely curious, if you try to walk the navigation property of an EF entity after the context is disposed, don't you get an exception?

Comment: @Graham: When you drill down into the non-existing nav prop, yes. But even without an ORM, you'd be getting a null reference exception anyway in that case. The ORM might change the particular exception but it doesn't change _that_ an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Flater, with EF, you have to explicitly declare which navigation properties to eagerly load, correct? So if you have a Car object with 6-7 different navigation properties ("Car.Engine.Name", "Car.Manufacturer.County", etc), then different method that all return the same core Car type would load different properties based on their needs?

Comment: @Graham: Eager loading is not a given, you can also lazy load in EF. I'm also ending the discussion here. This isn't the place to discuss your question; I suggest you post an actual question if you're looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Access modifiers and layer segregation.

Access modifiers (`public`, `private`, `internal`, `protected`) make it possible for you to *prevent* an external caller from calling *inner* logic directly, and instead *force* them to use only the logic you have allowed them to access.

If you abstract your data access logic into a separate project/layer (known as the DAL), then you can achieve what you want.

As a simple example:

```
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
}

public class EmployeeRepository
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        using(var db = new MyContext())
        {
            UpdateEmployeeList(db);

            return db.Employees.ToList();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateEmployeeList(MyContext db)
    {
        var externalEmployeeList = GetExternalEmployeeList();

        foreach(var employee in externalEmployeeList)
        {
            db.Add(employee);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

An external caller can only get at the employee data by doing the following:

```
var employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
var employees = employeeRepository.GetEmployees();
```

Therefore, it's impossible for them to bypass the additional SOAP call.

**However**, this does mean that external callers can't have direct access to `MyContext` and must always use methods that you've created for them.

In professional codebases, layer segregation is such a common occurrence that this is usually already the case anyway. I would expect any professional codebase to separate its DAL (data acccess layer) into a separate project and not leak its inner dependency (such as EF's `DbContext`).

---

While it's technically possible to do things like intercepting queries, this is not going to be easy to develop nor maintain.

What you're effectively asking for is the following:

> I want to force external callers to **use my logic** (= enforcing the additional SOAP call) instead of just using EF directly.

The logical consequence is that you **have to create your logic**. This is the DAL I was talking about, it's a project that exists specifically to separate the external caller from EF, and instead force the external caller to use the DAL's logic (which will use EF if and when it wants to - the external caller doesn't get to make the decision).

Comment: Does the concept of scaffolding from EF objects get broken to the point its not really usable with a DAL? And does that sort of create a custom framework around a framework? Are you starting to diminish the conveniences of EF?

Comment: @MattRalston: Yes and no. **Yes**, when you put a layer between the UI and EF, and wish for the UI to be able to use every feature of EF, then you have to ensure that the DAL exposes every feature. **No**, because this is implicitly what you're asking for - a way to separate the UI from EF so you can enforce your own business logic. If it were optional (not enforced), then you could give your UI access to both EF directly and your optional DAL, for which you only need to develop _additional_ features. But if you want to **enforce** using the DAL, you have to force your UI to only use your DAL.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to intercept the DB-Query. This enables you to execute custom code before the database-query is executed.
Check the following link: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx

In theory this will work but in my opinion it's a pretty bad way to call a SOAP service, which is completely independent of the DB, in some "random" interceptor.

Instead you should provide a class to your GUI-Models (?) that doesn't give them the EF DataContext itsself but a class that you control. This layer of the application called e.g. dataprovider then decides wether to call the SOAP service and update the db before querying it or not.

This is just a personal opinion of me.